# Services.exe cosuming high RAM usage

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I just want to ask for help on how to fix the services.exe which is consuming 80%-90% of my RAM. The issue is because of the IIS. I have a website running on IIS. So this server is a IIS-PHP-Mysql. If I'm going to stop IIS, it will go back to its normal condition but if I will start it again the services.exe will consume 80%-90% of my free RAM. Please help me with this issue. Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: We help with coding issues. Is there a specific piece of code that is causing this? If not I'd recommend serverfault or superuser.

Comment: This should probably be moved to serverfault

Comment: @chris85: No coding issues Sir since the program works well on other server. Okay. Thank you.